# Should I call a callback for an event triggered by a developer?

Tags: c, callbacks

I'm designing an API for a stream-processing library. The library will process a stream provided by the user and will transition between states based on the data in the stream. The state transitions are indicated via a callback.

But I want to be able to have the user force a state transition as well. In this case, should I call the callback? Here is a proposed API in C, where the state transition is simply "session started."

```
struct MyObj;

void add_callback(struct MyObj *obj, void (*session_started)(void));
void process_stream(struct MyObj *obj, uint8_t *stream_chunk, size_t chunk_size);

// Should the callback be called during this function?
void manually_start_session(struct MyObj *obj);
```

On the one hand if I call the callback then the user could place all of their handling code in the callback and not worry if it's called manually or not. But on the other hand, the user knows when they call `manually_start_session` so I don't see why I need to notify them that the session has started.

What is the best/most obvious/least surprising decision API here?

Comment: Would the actions be expected to be different if the event is decoded from the stream or manually triggered?

Comment: You said "the state transitions are indicated via a callback".

Answer (score 0):

For me, the most straightforward approach would be to leave the callbacks out of the manual call.  Presumably you already have something to handle state transitions, so a state transition caused by a call from your manual method should be handled no differently.

Assuming you're passing all the relative information pertaining to the state change to the one handling the state change transitions, it makes no difference whether or not the state change was caused manually or otherwise.  However if this *were* somehow handled differently, then if anything, I'd simply add the information in addition to the state change that this particular transition was manually called, say, using a flag.

Don't forget that [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) could be a very useful way of implementing changes in behavior at runtime in your case.  Just be sure that the assigning of a new strategy is performed in a critical block if you're using multiple threads which it seems you are.

Answer (score 0):

Put the actions that the callback takes into their own function, and call that function from the callback.

Now your users can call the new function directly.

I would avoid calling a function that is intended to be a callback directly.  Such functions often follow specific naming and signature conventions; calling it directly could be confusing to the fellow programmer trying to read your code later.